# i am trying to make a simple login page

Tags: jquery

i am trying to make a simple login page that will login for a username and password and take a successful login to a welcome screen. Want to use Jquery/Ajax and not php. how can i be done. I am stuck at this point.

JQuery

@import url(style.css);

$(document).ready(function () {
        //event handler for submit button
        $("#Login").click(function () {
            //collect userName and password entered by users
            var userName = $("#username").val();
            var password = $("#password").val();

            //call the authenticate function
            authenticate(userName, password);
        });
    });

    //authenticate function to make ajax call
    function authenticate(userName, password) {
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            //the url where you want to sent the userName and password to
            url: "http://your-url.com/secure/authenticate.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            //json object to sent to the authentication url
            data: '{"userName": "' + userName + '", "password" : "' + password + '"}',
            success: function () {
                //do any process for successful authentication here
            }
        })
    }

## Login Demo-

### Jquery Demonstration

```
  <h1>Login to Welcome Screen</h1>

  <h2> By me</h2>

  <img class="border_pic" src="images/images.jpg" alt="Screenshot" />

  <div class="border" id="login">

    <p>Username:

      <input type="text" size="30" name="username" id="username" />

      <br />

      Password:

      <input type="password" size="30" name="password" id="password" />

      <br />

      <input type="button" accesskey="l" id="Login" name="Login" value="Login" />

    </p>

  </div>
```

Hello guys.

Sup guys.

Signing off

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is a way to make asynchronous calls to the backend from javascript, so you can't do this with pure javascript. There are many ways to implement the backend portion, but the simplest for simple applications is probably PHP.

You can find about a million tutorials on the subject online: 
[Like this one](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http://www.queness.com/post/328/a-simple-ajax-driven-website-with-jqueryphp&ei=9wT6TYT5GY73gAfU9LidBQ&usg=AFQjCNF80WV71zKWMHfaWCQiVSmc2MbU1w&sig2=JEVy__p029bTOgXWPRg1vQ)
[Or this one](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCIQFjAB&url=http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/07/beginners-guide-to-using-ajax-with-jquery/&ei=9wT6TYT5GY73gAfU9LidBQ&usg=AFQjCNFJJsoZ9wwDLoQ6vuXDIK_sU6Kp2w&sig2=OnBatZUSZv-GKPkeHampkA)
[Or this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CDEQFjAD&url=http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-jquery-ajax/index.html&ei=9wT6TYT5GY73gAfU9LidBQ&usg=AFQjCNGKFuoP0vnxaciOxI4rgmYD8saAlg&sig2=VVTtV0q0Vfx6dfitCmFE_A)

Answer (score 0):

try this: http://www.bitrepository.com/ajax-login-modal-box.html